# Keyboard shortcut to produce code chunk brackets in markdown in R for RStudio

Tags: r, r-markdown

Is there a keyboard shortcut to produce code chunk brackets in Rmarkdown ?:

````
```{r}

```
````

Comment: On Mac OS is option + command + i

Comment: Wouldn't that depend on the editor you are using? Can you clarify? Are you using the R GUI? RStudio? Something else??

Comment: @MrFlick you are right. I walk talking about RStudio on Mac OS.

Comment: On Windows it's supposed to be ctrl alt I, but that produces an accented I on my laptop. Full list of shortcuts at https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200711853-Keyboard-Shortcuts

Comment: @SabDeM you answered first you want the points?

Comment: @Rhodo forget about it :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On a mac in RStudio: alt+cmd+i. It's under the "code" dropdown menu box if you forget it.

Answer (score 15):

on pc in RStudion it's: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>

Comment: Same chord on linux

Comment: For me, ctrl + alt + i gives me accented i (í). How do I make the shortcut work like it's used to?

Comment: In the newest RStudio release (v 1.1.383), you can modify any shortcut you want via the top drop-down menus:  Tools >> Modify Keyboard Shortcuts...