# Editing keyboard shortcut to produce code chunk in R studio

Tags: python, r, rstudio, reticulate

I'm using Rmd in RStudio to edit in different languages, including Python, bash and R. I am wondering if there is a way to edit the "insert code chunk" option and/or its keyboard shortcut.

I would like to have a shortcut to insert a Python code chunk, another for bash, and another for R code chunks. Is this possible?

For reference, [this is how you insert a new code chunk in RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938280/keyboard-shortcut-to-produce-code-chunk-brackets-in-markdown-in-r-for-rstudio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to <kbd>Tools</kbd> → <kbd>Modify Keyboard Shortcuts</kbd>  in <kbd>RStudio</kbd>, you will get something like this:

[image]

Then filter by `chunk`, put your desired shortcut for that languages and then <kbd>Apply</kbd>:

[image]